# What happens to the memory that was 'moved into'?

Tags: rust, move

Does rust drop the memory after `move` is used to reassign a value?

What happens to the string `"aaa"` in this example?

```
let mut s = String::from("aaa");
s = String::from("bbb");
```

I'm guessing that the `"aaa"` String is dropped - it makes sense, as it is not used anymore. However, I cannot find anything confirming this in the docs. (for example, [the Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) only provides an explanation of what happens when we assign a new value using `move`).

I'm trying to wrap my head around the rules Rust uses to ensure memory safety, but I cannot find an explicit rule of what happens in such a situation.

Comment: So, after [some testing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=86ee7e13ebbbd44fefff1af9b46f107f), it appears that the `"aaa"` is indeed dropped. However, I still cannot find a rule that would say why it happens.

Comment: According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html a value that is overwritten is dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move semantics are implicit here. The data in `s` is initialized by moving from the `String` produced by `String::from("bbb")`. The original data stored in `s` is dropped by side-effect (the process of replacing it leaves it with no owner, so it's dropped as part of the operation).

Per [the destructor documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#destructors) (emphasis added):

> When an initialized variable or temporary goes out of scope, its destructor is run, or it is dropped. **Assignment also runs the destructor of its left-hand operand, if it's initialized.** If a variable has been partially initialized, only its initialized fields are dropped.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, assignment to a variable will drop the value that is being replaced.

Not dropping the replaced value would be a disaster - since `Drop` is frequently used for deallocation and other cleanup, if the value wasn't dropped, you'd end up with all sorts of leaks.